# Every second execution of JUnit 5 tests of maven project in eclipse results in 'No tests found with test runner JUnit 5'

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-jdt

I am facing a problem with the execution of a JUnit 5 launch configuration in eclipse.
The project in which the source code as well as the test code resides is a maven project.
The launch configuration seems to be setup correctly, because right after a build the tests are executed without a problem.
If I execute the same launch configuration a second time, this results in the above mentioned error producing the following stack trace in the console window:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/commons/util/Preconditions
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.create(LauncherFactory.java:83)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.create(LauncherFactory.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.<init>(JUnit5TestLoader.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createRawTestLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.defaultInit(RemoteTestRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.init(RemoteTestRunner.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:208)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.commons.util.Preconditions
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 13 more
```

A subsequent execution of the launch configuration will again work correctly.
This goes on and on - one execution works fine, the subsequent one fails.
As you can imagine, this is a pretty annoying situation.

I traced the problem a bit deeper and can tell, that the given stack trace only shows a symptom not the root cause.
The class Preconditions present in the local maven repository (in package junit-platform-commons) and this package is part of recursive maven dependencies.

As far as I could identify the problem so far, the classpaths of the URLClassLoaders are not set correctly in the failing case.

In the working case, I see two of the ClassLoaders - one containing the paths for the java runtime jars and the second containing  my project jar and all the jars of my maven dependencies in the local .m2 repository.

In the failing case, I see again two ClassLoaders - the first one again with the paths for the java runtime, but the second containing my project jar and instead of my maven dependencies only some paths to

```
eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/1135/0/.cp/
eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/1137/0/.cp/
eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/1373/0/.cp/
eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/1138/0/.cp/lib/javaagent-shaded.jar
```

As far as I understand, the classpath setting in the launch configuration has a immediate effect on the paths in these URLClassLoaders. 
But this seems to be broken in my case every second execution.

Has anyone observed the same behavior or even better has a solution or hint for me how to solve this problem?

Looking forward to your help,
  Frank

environment:
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)
Build id: 20190917-1200
All plugins are up-to-date.

Comment: I assume you are executing the tests from the IDE, right? A clean & build is always a good option, have you tried? Also, you could execute the tests from the terminal `mvn clean package` will execute the tests, maybe it could provide you more information about the problem.

Comment: Yes, I execute the tests from within the eclipse IDE. Clean & build unfortunately does not solve the problem.
Concerning the test execution via command line - this works fine, also multiple times.
But I want to execute the tests in the IDE as well without problems. It is more convenient for debugging purposes.

So solving the original test execution problem would be beneficial.

Comment: Alright, the `mvn clean package` was for discard problems with the maven configuration, since the tests run ok outside the IDE, then the problem is in the IDE. Could you try to import your project into another workspace? Maybe there are conflicts with the .settings of whatever.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. You were completely right. There was something wrong with the eclipse settings. I guess there was something screwed up during several update sessions of the workspace.

I first tried to install a complete new workspace and imported the project. Worked like a charm many times after each other.
Because I wanted to stay with the old workspace due to the reuse of many individual setting, I spent some time to figure out which part of the settings were the problematic ones.
I could narrow it down to org.eclipse.core.runtime.
Problem solved! Thank you :)